# GridBagLayout not showing JTextArea, and showing panel in center

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

In the following code, when I add the JTextArea to the main panel, it doesn't show up. When I add the controlPanel, it shows up in the center, not the edge. I'm new with GridBagLayout, so I'm assuming I'm missing something simple.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        controlPanel.add(new JButton("Play"));
        controlPanel.add(new JButton("Pause"));
        controlPanel.add(new JSpinner());
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        mainPanel.add(textArea, c);
        // mainPanel.add(controlPanel, c);
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setLocation(250, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This is how the constraints look after your suggestions. The textArea still does not show up.

```
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
//      c.gridheight = 3;
//      c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        mainPanel.add(textArea, c);
        // mainPanel.add(controlPanel, c);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
```

Comment: Why are you expecting it to show up on the edge?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Isn't that what gridx = 0 and gridy = 0 means?

Comment: No, they're just arbitrary grid numbers. For GB, add a spacer component to the right with some weightx.

Comment: You've got to add non-zero weights to the GridBagConstraints (weightx and weighty), else all will bunch up in the center. Consider reading the tutorials on any new thing you learn before using it. It's a skill that's worked well for me.

Comment: Ok, but what if I wanted it to start at the left edge and fill the panel horizontally? Then I couldn't put a spacer component to the right, correct?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I had tried using weights but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your updated [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget weights *and* anchors:

```
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
```

**Edit:**
Example of adding row and column values to the JTextArea:

```
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("Play"));
    controlPanel.add(new JButton("Pause"));
    controlPanel.add(new JSpinner());

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), c);
```

Comment: It positioned the controlPanel in the right place, but the textArea doesn't show up. Any idea why?

Comment: @gsingh: It's probably got a very small size. Consider using the Text area constructor that accepts rows and columns and passing in reasonable numbers, say 20 rows and 40 columns, and also you should put the JTextArea in a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 1):

My totally serious answer would be to not use GridBagLayout. Leave GridBagLayout for the GUI form builders.

If you want to build GUI's by hand (I recommend building them by hand and avoiding form builders, BTW) then generally BorderLayout with nested panels using BoxLayouts are really your best bet.